# Pass down Console Handle to child

Tags: .net, winapi

This is a .NET question

Suppose I create a command line process with via a [ProcessStartInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) that specifies:

- NoShellExecute
- CreateNoWindow
- RedirectStandardOutput
- ... and stderr + stdin

I can read it's output as a ByteStream and print it on my own Console. Fine.

But if my child process chooses to set the cursor position, that will not happen.

This makes sense, since it doesn't have it's own window (due to the CreateNoWindow option) and does not own a virtual console. Thus it does not have a valid Handle to pass to [SetCursorPosition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686025(v=vs.85).aspx)

So what I'm asking is:

How can I grant my child process access to my own Console Handle?
So that it can behave as if it was owning the Console (Window)

I know the Powershell can do it, but I don't know whether it uses WindowsAPI or has some .NET way to do it.

Comment: You don't need to do anything special to allow the child to write to the console.  Just don't specify output redirection.  (And you probably want to turn off CreateNoWindow too.)

Comment: Ok. This was a classic example of overthinking on my part.